# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'sortAscending' property"

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

**Here is the code that makes the SOAP call**

```
require_once("zulutradeClient.php");
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$params->providerId = 128391;
$params->validTrades = true;
$params->lotSize = "Standard";
$params->start = 0;
$params->length = 20;
//$params->sortAscending = false;
$params->fromDateStr = "1986-08-27T09:00:00";
$params->toDateStr = "2014-01-12T09:00:00";
$params->sortBy = "dc";

$ztclient = new zulutradeClient();
$response = "";

try {
    $response = $ztclient->GetProviderTrades( $params );
    var_dump($response);
}
catch (SoapFault $e) {
   var_dump($e); 
}
```

**The wsdl is here**

```
http://www.zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx?WSDL
```

When the 'sortAscending' is commented out, i get the no property error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'sortAscending' property"
```

When it is uncommented I get the following error:

```
message: Could not connect to host
faultcode: http
```

It seems really hopeless, I've tried everything, and it just doesn't want to take that parameter.

Comment: Have you tried sending a array instead of an object?

Comment: Yeah, it's the same thing with the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
When the 'sortAscending' is commented out, i get the no property error:

SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'sortAscending' property"

<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sortAscending" type="s:boolean" />
```

sortAscending is a mandatory field in wsdl, that's why you are getting above error.

```
When it is uncommented I get the following error:

 message: Could not connect to host
 faultcode: http
```

There is no fault in your request soap message here. The issue here is, this end point url.

```
http://www.zulutrade.com:81/WebServices/Performance.asmx
```

It is not accessible. Connect with your wsdl provider regarding this. you can not do anything about that.
Most probably, this srvice would be hosted on some other port rather than 81.

Comment: I've already contacted them, let's see what they say, I'll update it here when i get the response.

Comment: Actually, i also tried this service from soapui and i am getting same response i.e connection refused. So i am almost sure there's something wrong with their service end point url.

Comment: They contacted me, it's not a public api